# Python - printing multiple shortest and longest words from a list

Tags: python, arrays, list, sorting

I need to go through a list and print the longest words in it. I can do this for just one word, but can't figure out how to print more than one, if there are two words that are three letters long, for instance. 
I've tried

```
list.sort (key=len, reverse =True)
print ("The longest word in the list is: " , list[0])
```

This works but only prints the first longest, which is no good for more than one longest word.

I've also tried :

```
p=0
for item in list:
    if len (item) > p:
        s=item
        p = len(item)
print (s)
```

This also the same as the previous code

I also need to do this for the shortest word in the list.

Apologies if this isn't a good question, it's my first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your existing code could actually be modified to work without much trouble. Instead of keeping a single string in `s`, keep a `list` of strings. If you find one that's the same length as the previous longest, `append` it. If you find one that's even longer, throw out the `list` and start a new one. Like this:

```
p=0
s=[]
for item in lst:
    if len(item) > p:
        s=[item]
        p=len(item)
    elif len(item) == p:
        s.append(item)
print(s)
```

Comment: This is much easier and works very well, I've found. But is there a way to adapt it for the shortest word?

Comment: For the shortest word - I've set p as the length of the longest word, but is there a better way to do this, as the shortest word could be changed to be greater than this value. I could just set it to 100 of something but it looks a little tacky.

Comment: If you want a number which is larger than any other number, use infinity—which is unfortunately spelled `float('inf')` in Python. Otherwise, your second idea is exactly right. (You could also use `sys.maxsize` in this case, which is the size of the largest possible collection. But infinity is more idiomatic and obvious, I think.)

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, don't *ever* use `list` as a variable name as it will override the built in type and could cause trouble later on.

You could do this for the longest words:

```
for i in lst:
    if len(i) == max(lst, key=len):
        print(i)
```

And for the shortest words:

```
for i in lst:
    if len(i) == min(lst, key=len):
        print(i)
```

The first code prints the strings which have the same length as the longest string. The second does the same, but with the shortest strings.

A small optimisation would be to precalculate the max/min length before the loop, so you don't need to recalculate it every time.

```
maxLen = max(lst, key=len)
for i in lst:
    if len(i) == maxLen:
        print(i)
```

The same can be done for the other loop.

Comment: Sorry, I was just using list for this question, and thank you very much for the answer.

Comment: You should calculate the `max` and `min` values before you start the loop. There's no need to do it again and again and again and again ...

Answer (score 1):

Volatility's answer is great, but let's look at another way to do this.

What if you not only had the list in sorted order, but also had it grouped into batches of the same length? Then this would be easy: Print the first group, and print the last group.

And there's a function that comes with Python that does that grouping for you, [`itertools.groupby`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby), so it *is* easy:

```
l.sort(key=len) # puts them in order
groups = list(itertools.groupby(l, key=len))
print('The shortest words are: {}'.format(groups[0][1])
print('The longest words are: {}'.format(groups[-1][1])
```

You could turn that into a one-liner:

```
groups = list(itertools.groupby(sorted(l, key=len), key=len))
```

However, I don't think I would in this case; that repeated `key=len` and all those extra parentheses make it harder to read.

Meanwhile, you can avoid creating the whole list of groups when you only really want the first:

```
l.sort(key=len)
shortest = itertools.groupby(l, key=len)
print('The shortest words are: {}'.format(next(shortest)[1]))
longest = itertools.groupby(reversed(l), key=len)
print('The longest words are: {}'.format(next(longest)[1]))
```

However, unless the `list` is really huge, I wouldn't worry about this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a dict to collect the words:

```
results = {}
for word in words:
   if len(word) not in results:
      results[len(word)] = []
   results[len(word)].append(word)
```

Next sort the dictionary by the keys, which are the lengths and print the words. This prints the longest words first, to reverse it, remove `reverse=True`:

```
for i in sorted(results.keys(), reverse=True):
   print 'Number of words with length {}: {}'.format(i,len(results[i]))
   for word in results[i]:
      print word
```

To print only the shortest and longest:

```
shortest = sorted(results.keys())[0]
longest = sorted(results.keys(), reverse=True)[0]

print 'Shortest words:'

for word in results[shortest]:
   print word

print 'Longest words:'

for word in results[longest]:
   print word
```

Answer (score 0):

Can always use a lambda function as well

```
longest = len(sorted(list, key=len)[-1])
filter(lambda item: len(item) == longest, list)
```

will yield the longest words

```
shortest = len(sorted(list, key=len)[0])
filter(lambda item: len(item) == shortest, list)
```

Will yield the shortest words

Comment: First, why would you use `lambda x: len(x)` instead of just `len`? It has the exact same result, but it's harder to read (and longer and slower and easier to get wrong). Second, the OP wants all the strings tied for shortest length, not just 3.

Comment: I didn't know that implementation, fair enough, but I'm still using a lambda on filter

Answer (score -1):

```
list.sort (key=len, reverse =True)
print ("The longest 3 words in the list are: " , list[:3])
```

Comment: The OP wants all the words tied for the shortest length, not 3 of them.